# Simplify $\bar{a}\bar{b}(\bar{a} + b)(\bar{b} + b)$

Tags: boolean-algebra

I've managed to simplify $\bar{a}\bar{b}(\bar{a} + b)(\bar{b} + b)$ to
$\bar{a} +\bar{a}\bar{b}$

Where $\bar{a}$ = $a$ complement
I simplified the original expression with Huntingtons Postulates, Idempotent laws etc

I've checked they are equivalent by truth table.
Can this be simplified even further?

Comment: What is the topic? What is $a$. What is $\overline{a}$? What did you try so far? Please expand the question.

Comment: @Kolja Sorry if the question is vague, I will edit it now. The topic is Boolean algebra/functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that $xx = x$, $\bar{x} + x = 1$, and $\bar{x}x = 0$ for all $x$.

\begin{align}
\bar{a}\bar{b}(\bar{a} + b)(\bar{b} + b) &= \bar{a}\bar{b}(\bar{a}+b) \\
&= \bar{a}\bar{b}\bar{a} + \bar{a}\bar{b}b \\
&= \bar{a}\bar{a}\bar{b} \\
&= \bar{a}\bar{b}. 
\end{align}

Line 1: $\bar{x}+x = 1$,
Line 2: $x(y+z) = xy + xz$,
Line 3: $\bar{x}x=0$,
Line 4: $xx = x$.

Comment: I really confused myself by implementing the complement law incorrectly... Thanks for clearing that up!